# Python write/read text to online server

Tags: database, python-3.x, python-requests, send

I need to do a python messenger. 
Does anyone know how to upload and read the message to/from online server?

Comment: You can check this resources in order to start modelling your problem:
[server-client python chat](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_network_programming_tcp_server_client_chat_server_chat_client_select.php),
[Flask socket-IO chat](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO-Chat),
[Python simple chat](https://gist.github.com/mako34/7113011)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in to the [sockets library](https://pythonprogramming.net/python-sockets/)!

Additionally, if you want to make it look beautiful and have a bunch of other functionality, I would look into using [Flask (a web framework)](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and [Flask-SocketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Using sockets will allow you to have a client connect to a server and relay information to it which can then be processed and passed on to other clients, echoed back to the original client, etc.